# Not able to set width of a horizontal linear layout or height of vertical linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have made a fragment layout for which code is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bill_display_id"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:context=".HomePage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/zoom">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bill_text_id"
            />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scroll_horiz_id">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/zoom_lin">

                <View
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/prd_id">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Product"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/rate_id">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rate"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/qty_id">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Qty"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/price_id">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Price"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Now i have a function **setZoom** (shown below) in which i am trying to set height and width of horizontal linear layout (id = zoom_lin).
But i am seeing that only height is getting set and not width.

```
protected void setZoom(float val)
{

    View horz_lin = rootView.findViewById(R.id.zoom_lin);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = horz_lin.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = 300;    // 300 is a random number for testing only
    lp.height = 600;   // 600 is a random number for testing only
    horz_lin.requestLayout();

}
```

Similarly if i try to set height and width for vertical linear layout (id = zoom), i see that only width is getting set and not height.

Is there any rule which forbids us from setting the width for horiizontal linear layout and height for vertical linear layout.

Please excuse me if am missing something trivial as i am a beginner in android development.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the updated layoutParams back to the linear layout:

```
protected void setZoom(float val)
{

    LinearLayout horz_lin = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.zoom_lin);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = horz_lin.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = 300;    // 300 is a random number for testing only
    lp.height = 600;   // 600 is a random number for testing only
    horz_lin.setLayoutParams(lp); // ADD THIS LINE
    horz_lin.requestLayout();

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this won't fix anything.
As i mentioned in the question, the height is getting set but the width isn't.
Same with the line that you suggested.